# How to return TitanVertex from TitanGraphQuery

Tags: nosql, graph-databases, titan

I want to use a list of properties (Multi-Value keys), so I have to use `addProperty()` instead of `setProperty()`. To do this I have to use `TitanVertex` instead of (Blueprints') `Vertex`, or?

When I do a query in Java I always get `Vertex` back. How can I use `TitanVertex` instead? Where are methods like `getTitanVertex()` or `query.titanVertices()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titan is a native implementation of [Blueprints](http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com) and thus returns a Blueprints `Vertex` object and therefore the reason why you don't get back a `TitanVertex`.  Note that `TitanVertex` implements Blueprints `Vertex`:

http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.4.2/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanVertex.html

so you should be able to cast `Vertex` to `TitanVertex`.

```
TitanVertex v = (TitanVertex) g.getVertex(...)
```